# fail to start typescript compiled file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have converted big JS project to typescript (as I C# programmer) using in PhantomJs.
The problem is interpreter (phantomjs) fails while executing this js file.

```
D:\My\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe --load-images=false --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=no --cookies-file=cookies C:\Users\alex\Projects\robot\bo.js
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.prototype')
```

the code is:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype; // <<< here
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

So. I think the problem is somewhat related to inheritance.
Have any one encountered this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: does http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground compiles your code? or maybe a peace of code? It is also possible to generate source maps for typescript and inspect buggy part of typescript in devtools in chrome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most common cause of this error is that you are loading the files in the wrong order... for example...

File A

```
class ExampleClass {
    someMethod() {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
}
```

File B

```
class ExampleSubClass extends ExampleClass {

}
```

If you were to load `File B` before `File A`, you would get the exact error you are describing. (This includes forgetting to load `File A` or loading `File A` after `File B`).

Fixes

If you are combining all of your files into a single file (and you are probably using a `_references.ts` file) make sure the references are in the right order.

```
/// <reference path="file-a.ts" />
/// <reference path="file-b.ts" />
```

If you are using script tags, it is the similar fix (making sure you are using `.js` extensions and checking the order of loading)...

```html
<script src="file-a.js"></script>
<script src="file-b.js"></script>
```